# How to fetch pageXOffset and pageYOffset in puppeteer/playwright

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, playwright

I would like to fetch pageXOffset & pageYOffset for the element. Here is code I have tried

```
        const pageXOffset = await page.evaluate(()=>window.pageXOffset)
        const pageYOffset = await page.evaluate(() => window.pageYOffset)
```

where `element` is `ElementHandle`.
But somehow I get Offset values to be zero. Wondering what I am missing over here

Comment: ok the problem was because I had not scrolled. So returning zero values made sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok the problem was because I had not scrolled. So returning zero values made sense